# How to extract model information from the model name?

Tags: r

I have a vector of time series model names as follow,consider the name of the vector as **model**:

```
  [1] "ARIMA(2,1,0) with drift" "ARIMA(2,0,0) with non-zero mean" "ARIMA(2,0,0) with non-zero mean" "ARIMA(2,0,0) with non-zero mean" "ARIMA(0,0,1) with non-zero mean"
```

These vectors contain five different parts:

1) **Model Name**: There is always a model name before the parenthesis, In this case "ARIMA" is a model name( ARIMA is a forecasting technique that projects the future values of a series based entirely on its own inertia, shorthand for Autoregressive integrated moving average)

2) **The Auto regressive part**(AR part referred as "p"): The first number after the parenthesis before the comma is the Autoregressive part, so for example these vectors as shown above has values 2,2,2,2,0 for AR part.

3) **The Moving Average part** (referred as "d"): The second element in the parenthesis right after the first comma is called the moving average part.
In this example, I have 1,0,0,0,0 as moving averages

4) **The Differencing** part (referred as "q"): The last element in the parenthesis is the differencing part mostly referred as "q" in terminology.
In this example, I have 0,0,0,0,1 as values.

5) The other two parts right after "with" are the drift and non zero part.

The problem is that I need to extract these elements from the model vector.

By looking at the model name I want to write a program to extract the followings:

```
 1. Name of the model eg: ARIMA 
 2. Number of AR coefficients 
 3. Number of MA coefficients 
 4. Order of differencing 
 5. Whether the model has a drift or not 
 6. whether it has a zero mean or not
```

My output should look like this:

```
   Model p d q outcome_with_drift outcome_with_non_zero_mean
 1 ARIMA 2 1 0                  1                          0
 2 ARIMA 2 0 0                  0                          1
 3 ARIMA 2 0 0                  0                          1
 4 ARIMA 2 0 0                  0                          1
 5 ARIMA 0 0 1                  0                          1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `library(stringr)` to extract the vectors into different columns, for example, if vect is a vector which has below inputs:

```
vect <- c("ARIMA(2,1,0) with drift", "ARIMA(2,0,0) with non-zero mean" ,"ARIMA(2,0,0) with non-zero mean" ,
          "ARIMA(2,0,0) with non-zero mean" ,"ARIMA(0,0,1) with non-zero mean")
```

then use `str_split_fixed` to extract it into separate columns as below:

```
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(str_split_fixed(vect,"\\s|\\(|\\)|,",n=5))
###Here we have choosen the separator as space(\\s), parenthesis ( \\( and \\) ) and commas (,)

names(df) <- c("Model","p","d","q","outcome")
#Rename basis the question, into follwing:
#p is the number of autoregressive terms(AR)
#d is the number of nonseasonal differences needed for stationarity(MA)
#q is the number of lagged forecast errors in the prediction equation(order of differencing)

df$outcome_ <- gsub("\\s|-","_",trimws(df$outcome))
#cleaning the outcome column by replacing spaces and dashes with underscores
dummy_mat <- data.frame(model.matrix(~outcome_-1,data=df))
#using model.matrix to calculate the dummies for drift and non zero mean, for the value of 1 meaning True and 0 meaning False
df_final <- data.frame(df[,1:4],dummy_mat)
```

**Outcome**:

```
#   Model p d q outcome_with_drift outcome_with_non_zero_mean
# 1 ARIMA 2 1 0                  1                          0
# 2 ARIMA 2 0 0                  0                          1
# 3 ARIMA 2 0 0                  0                          1
# 4 ARIMA 2 0 0                  0                          1
# 5 ARIMA 0 0 1                  0                          1
```

Comment: Thanks, this what I wanted!